# Javascript/jQuery: Why different result for event.target using <a> tag Vs. other Elements in console.log, alert() with $(this) in mind

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

There seems to be something worth understanding when handling DOM using event.log.

Comparing the results in an alert and the console.log in firebug.

I have this Code HTML:

```
<div>Click Me < Div ></div>
<a href="#">Click Me < a ></a>
```

and JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('div').click(function(e){

        console.log(e.target);
        console.log($(this));
        alert(e.target)
        alert($(this))
    })

    $('a').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();

        console.log(e.target);
        console.log($(this));

        alert(e.target)
        alert($(this))
    })
})
```

When the Div or  is Clicked:

The `console.log` of both work as expect

But the `alert`s show up with different outputs:

For DIV:

> 1   objectHTMLDivElement
>   2   object Object `//using jQuery's $(this)`

However, when the `<a>` tag is Clicked it yields:

> 1   The web address or the `href` attribute's value
>
> 2   object Object `//using jQuery's $(this)`

Why is this the case? Why doesn't the alert of `<a>` print this tag as being the HTMLElement?

Please test for yourself here:
http://jsfiddle.net/hWR53/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All objects, among them elements, have [a `toString` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString), and this `toString` function is called on the object to build what is displayed in the alert.

For most objects, this function returns `"[object Object]"` but instances of `a` elements have it overridden to return the value of the `href` property of the element.

Comment: So you mean you can use this logic in getting the `href` from <a> apart from the traditional `e.target.href`? or this is reserved only to the `alert()`?

Comment: It's not reserved to the alert, you can do `''+yourElement` to get the href but I don't see any advantage over `yourElement.href`.

Comment: You can try this in your console in this page : `''+$('a[href]').get(0)`.

Comment: that's ok. I appreciate.. what am asking is whether it is possible to get the `href` of the `a` in the same manner that the `alert` is getting it... or what is the `alert` doing to get the `href` apart from getting it from `e.target.href`?

Comment: What the alert is doing is calling theElement.toString(), just like you implicitly do when calling ''+theElement. Is there something I'm missing in your question ?