# Form selector for multi-form page

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation, jquery-selectors

I've got a page with half a dozen forms on it.  I'm using jQuery 2.02, JQM 1.3.1 as well as jQuery Validate 1.12.0 with the *additional methods* add-on to try to validate the forms. I'm trying to use this selector to grab the relevant form when the user clicks on the submit button:

```
$('[id^=formEvent_]').validate({
```

which works great...for the first form encountered in the HTML (`formEvent_assign`, see fiddles below), in other words it always selects the first form no matter which form the user actually used.

I've tried

```
$('[id^=formEvent_]').closest('form').validate({
```

Setting a variable for the form EG:

```
var formPointer = "formEvent_terminate";
$('#' + formPointer).validate({
```

as well as:

```
var formPointer = "#formEvent_terminate";
$(formPointer).validate({
```

none of which work, as well as several other things I've found on SO.  I've been struggling with this for hours and it seems like a simple thing.  I can see in `console.log` that the right form object is being created, and I can see it's children (all the inputs), etc., but the selector doesn't allow validation to run.

**What selector should I use so I can have the Submit button from the individual forms run validation properly?**

Here's a list of seemingly pertinent SO questions I've read and tried, but ended up not being able to get to work for one reason or another:

[**Jquery validating a specific form on a page with multiple forms**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22057911/jquery-validating-a-specific-form-on-a-page-with-multiple-forms)

[**this input submit selector with closest form submit**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175520/this-input-submit-selector-with-closest-form-submit)

[**Javascript/jQuery: Why different result for event.target using  tag Vs. other Elements in console.log, alert() with $(this) in mind**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18561700/javascript-jquery-why-different-result-for-event-target-using-a-tag-vs-other)

Here's the full validation code & call to the submit routine if the form is valid:

```
$('[id^=formEvent_]').validate({
    submitHandler: function ( form, event) {
        isFormValid( form, event );
    },
    rules: {
        pcbid_assign: {
            required: true,
            digits: true,
            rangelength: [3, 6]
        },
        pcbid_terminate: {
            required: true,
            digits: true,
            rangelength: [3, 6]
        },
        input_reason_terminate: {
            required: true
        },
        input_assign_sbeJobNumber: {
            require_from_group: [1, ".assign_group"]
        },
        input_assign_sbeModelNumber: {
            require_from_group: [1, ".assign_group"]
        },
        input_assign_sbePN: {
            require_from_group: [1, ".assign_group"]
        },
        input_assign_sbeSerialNumber: {
            require_from_group: [1, ".assign_group"]
        }
    },
    messages: {
        pcbid_assign: "Please enter a valid PCBID with 3-6 digits.",
        input_assign_sbeJobNumber: "Please enter a valid job number.",
        input_assign_sbeModelNumber: "Please enter a valid model number.", 
        input_assign_sbePN: "Please enter a valid part number.",
        input_assign_sbeSerialNumber: "Please enter a valid serial number.",
        pcbid_terminate: "Please enter a valid PCBID with 3-6 digits.",
        input_reason_terminate: "Please enter a reason for this PCBID board's termination."
    }
});
```

Here are a couple of fiddles that exhibit the expected behavior (because they only have a single form in each):

[Assign with validation](http://jsfiddle.net/delliottg/X4WBF/)

[Terminate with validation](http://jsfiddle.net/delliottg/DFPH9/)

Comment: Are you trying to validate all the forms at once or just the "active" form?

Comment: Just the active form.  I'm building a generic JS object that will be sent via AJAX to an ASP.NET code-behind page for further processing (updating, querying or inserting into a MySQL database).  The same object will always be sent, just the data will vary by which form is submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try with `.each()` method?
Something like `$('[id^=formEvent_]').each(function() { $(this).validate({....`

Comment: I was able to get this working reliably today, thanks for the suggestion.  I'll post a working fiddle of my final code (still working on nuances for validation).  Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

If the submit button is inside the form you can use this simple "vanilla" JavaScript.

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="$(this.form).validate();"/>
```

`this.form` will always get you the containing form.

Comment: Can this also be done in the JS file?  Or do I need to add the entire validate function here in the HTML?  I'm going to give this a try as written & see what happens.

Comment: You can call whatever you want from within the submit button... even just `doStuff(this);` or `doStuff(this.form);` likewise you can bind this with jQuery too.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I decided to go the @kmsdev's answer below as it worked quite well in my circumstance, but your's seems very viable as well.